Old distro version on new hardware
I am trying to install CentOS 6 on new hardware for testing because our software is dependent on the package versions in CentOS 6. The trivial answer would be to update the software to run on a newer version since CentOS 6 is well past EOL, but I'm not a software dev and we will be looking at the LOE soon.
The current state:

The machine has an Intel 13th gen i5-1335U processor with a UEFI only BIOS (no legacy mode) and secure boot disabled
CentOS 7.5+ and Debian 10.0+ works, but earlier versions do not
I am using x86_64 installers and burning them to removable media with Rufus in UEFI mode
I have verified that when installing they are using GPT partitions
The installers themselves will boot into GRUB (legacy or 2), but when it tries to load the kernel and initrd/initramfs it fails
Currently I have Debian 12 installed with CentOS 6 so Debian is controlling Grub 2, but it still won't boot into CentOS 6
-Older hardware which have legacy mode in their BIOS is able to use both MBR & GPT partitions and boot CentOS 6 (Intel Atom E3845)
I am able to virtulize RHEL 6 in Qemu running in Debian 12

Failed attempts to fix so far:

Recreated the RHEL 6 initramfs in Debian 12
Modify the RHEL 6 GRUB 2 entry
Use the GRUB 2 OS prober to create a RHEL 6 entry
When loading an installer it either goes to a blinking cursor or the GRUB splash image is frozen on screen. In that state I am not able to switch to any TTYs
Adding echo statements to a custom GRUB entry makes it seem that it loads the initramfs. It shows the echo statements before loading the kernel, after loading the kernel but before loading initramfs, and after loading initramfs. After the echo statements show on screen it either reboots the machine or hangs with no TTYs.

My current theories:

The kernels are not compiled with necessary modules/parameters
There is something with initrd/iniramfs which is preventing the kernel from booting
The intel microcode included with the installers does not support the newer processor
Even though secure boot has been disabled I need to install a self-signed MOK & shim

Any ideas on why an older distro won't load on new hardware?

Why not run a CentOS 6 container?

@muru: TBH I haven't worked with containers. I am looking into how quickly CentOS 6 will boot using Debian 12 & Qemu and see if it is significantly slower than on bare metal. Would running CentOS 6 in a container have less overhead or boot faster than emulating?

How does it fail though? What does failure look like? Any error messages? What are they? Please [edit] those into your question.

Updated with how it fails.

Just install a modern Linux on your new machine and create a centos 6 VM using QEMU or some other hypervisor. This is the fastest, cheapest and most compatible solution. Go for it!

If you go down the virtualisation route ... use KVM, Xen or even the now free VMware workstation, qemu is way slower by comparison.

Right now I am trying to get a cloud (qcow2) image of CentOS 6 to run in Qemu in a headless Debian environment to drag race it against CentOS 6 on the older bare metal. If it is anywhere close in boot time/responsiveness I'll look into KMV, Xen, and VMware workstation. Thanks @tink!

You're welcome. One route of establishing why it won't complete would be to go to https://catalog.redhat.com/search?searchType=hardware&certified_RedHat_Platforms=Red%20Hat%20Enterprise%20Linux&certified_versions=Red%20Hat%20Enterprise%20Linux%206&p=1&certified_architectures=x86_64 and narrow down the hardware ... not that that solves the problem at hand, but it may explain it.

In no version of reality is a VM going to be faster than a container.

tink: Unfortunately, I am working with a tablet from a small company, so they wouldn't have certifications from Red Hat.
muru: Thanks! I'll look into using a container for my use case and drag race that against bare metal.

@tink you're confusing a few things. QEMU makes full use of KVM when possible. So, your advise is counter-productive: the way most KVM-based VMs are run is probably Qemu.

@GrandInformation How is performance an issue? You're replacing really old hardware with new hardware. Even if a VM is 50% slower than running natively, it's still faster than it used to be. So, rather than spending brain on this, get it running first, and if performance or power is a problem, you can still migrate to a container. Do what gets you there first, then optimize.

Marcus Muller: I'm going from an Atom E3845 to a 13th gen i5 (1335U), so I am skipping a decade or more. I know there are ways to lock things down, but my concern with running a VM is that the customer is very security conscious. I'll go down the VM/container rabbit hole, but would prefer a bare metal solution.

how is a VM less secure than running native? The opposite is the case.

Playing devil's advocate here, but the host OS is another attack vector when it is booting up.

yes, an End-of-life OS running on bare metal is a massive vulnerability. A modern OS running a VM, well-isolating the confidential workload is the opposite. Really, you don't really seem to be talking out of knowledge there, maybe leave such decisions up to your (fairly certainly military… CentOS, old software and extremely security conscious?) customer if you can't assess what is OK or not – I can't do that for you, but all the arguments you bring seem just to serve the purpose of not actually getting this done in the 20 minutes it'd take.

Yeah, your operating system needs to be compatible with your hardware; there's no easy trick to teach an old OS how new hardware works.

Trying to install old software on new operating systems should generally be easier than install old operating systems on new hardware. If you haven't tried hard enough, try now.

You can run your old OS in a VM or a container. Both are easier to set up than installing natively, even on era-adequate hardware, so there's no reason to not simply install a modern operating system on your new hardware, and run CentOS 6 in a VM or as a container.


